# How to retrieve a specific property from a nested JSON object

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, json.net

I have a nested json object which looks like this

```
{{
  "id": "99ed8a1a-68fa-4464-b5cb-f116ede0a520",
  "title": "NUnitTestDemo",
  "has_children": true,
  "level": 0,
  "children": [
    {
      "id": "c41764b1-a59a-420b-b06e-9f97f3876e9b",
      "title": "TestScripts",
      "has_children": true,
      "level": 1,
      "children": [
        {
          "id": "cfba3d9e-d305-464d-9154-cdd2efcb5436",
          "title": "SmokeTest",
          "has_children": true,
          "level": 2,
          "children": [
            {
              "id": "b58596fc-aeab-4f20-8a91-85599c08c0fc",
              "title": "TestAdd",
              "has_children": false,
              "level": 3,
              "tag": "mytag,add",
              "property": "Testing Addition of Two numbers",
              "children": []
            },
            {
              "id": "c819746e-25b9-4c84-8fb4-28794c3b2fe4",
              "title": "TestSubtract",
              "has_children": false,
              "level": 3,
              "tag": "mytag,subtract",
              "property": "Testing Subtraction of Two numbers",
              "children": []
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "id": "7dce76a3-f318-4d49-920c-1d94b3ec9519",
          "title": "SmokeTest1",
          "has_children": true,
          "level": 2,
          "children": [
            {
              "id": "64bf771d-313b-44ce-b910-27945505dada",
              "title": "TestMultiply",
              "has_children": false,
              "level": 3,
              "tag": "mytag,add",
              "property": "Testing Addition of Two numbers",
              "children": []
            },
            {
              "id": "5d810bc0-a9af-4838-b8eb-5fc7c47e910a",
              "title": "TestDivide",
              "has_children": false,
              "level": 3,
              "tag": "mytag,subtract",
              "property": "Testing Subtraction of Two numbers",
              "children": []
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "id": "8af09935-93fa-4379-9aa4-9f809055d1ea",
          "title": "Sample",
          "has_children": true,
          "level": 2,
          "children": [
            {
              "id": "407944bd-437e-48cd-8af0-bbd2eb376e72",
              "title": "Tests",
              "has_children": true,
              "level": 3,
              "children": [
                {
                  "id": "01223a10-2dda-4e3c-9287-d49b0c08870d",
                  "title": "SmokeTest2",
                  "has_children": true,
                  "level": 4,
                  "children": [
                    {
                      "id": "6e3df5f1-bcca-40a8-9ed5-3eaa74558488",
                      "title": "TestA",
                      "has_children": false,
                      "level": 5,
                      "tag": "mytag,add",
                      "property": "Testing Addition of Two numbers",
                      "children": []
                    },
                    {
                      "id": "0414d2c3-e4c8-4e52-9584-6a9e8516a3e2",
                      "title": "TestB",
                      "has_children": false,
                      "level": 5,
                      "tag": "mytag,subtract",
                      "property": "Testing Subtraction of Two numbers",
                      "children": []
                    }
                  ]
                }
              ]
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "id": "7dbfcdfe-f6cb-4942-bcc6-3ec899aec674",
          "title": "MyTestFolder",
          "has_children": true,
          "level": 2,
          "children": [
            {
              "id": "16c3a197-824a-4309-bb97-24d454d448f5",
              "title": "MyTestClass",
              "has_children": true,
              "level": 3,
              "children": [
                {
                  "id": "c37f2d67-0db0-49bf-80e0-9e99d7e9d767",
                  "title": "TestC",
                  "has_children": false,
                  "level": 4,
                  "tag": "mytag,add",
                  "property": "Testing Addition of Two numbers",
                  "children": []
                },
                {
                  "id": "a91c8c04-8a60-4872-b990-db9f993ddbe5",
                  "title": "TestD",
                  "has_children": false,
                  "level": 4,
                  "tag": "mytag,subtract",
                  "property": "Testing Subtraction of Two numbers",
                  "children": []
                }
              ]
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}}
```

If you notice at every level there is a "children" array. Now, when I am searching for "MyTestFolder" inside the above mentioned json, it is returning me "null".

My function looks like this. It is written in C# and I am using Newtonsoft.json library.

I am using .NET Core 3.1

```
public JObject RetrieveSpecifiedJsonObject(string propertyName, JObject jsonObject)
{
    //propertyName is the property to be retrieved
    string title = jsonObject.SelectToken("title").ToString();
    if(title != propertyName)
    {
        JArray childArray = jsonObject.SelectToken("children") as JArray;
        for(int i=0; i<childArray.Count; i++)
        {
            JObject childArrElem = childArray[i] as JObject;
            string arrElemTitle = childArrElem.SelectToken("title").ToString();
            if(arrElemTitle != propertyName)
            {
                RetrieveSpecifiedJsonObject(propertyName, childArrElem);
            }
            else
            {
                return childArrElem;
            }
        }//FOR ENDS
        return null;
    }//IF title != propertyName ENDS
    else
    {
        return jsonObject;
    }
}
```

I guess it has to be a recursive function. But, not getting what to do. When I am searching.

FYI, I can't search like `jsonobject["children"][0]["MyTestFolder"]`. I may have to search for any node at any point of time. For that, I need to write a generic function.

Comment: _So, please try to provide me a generic solution for this._ Sorry, but this isn't a free code writing service

Comment: Hi Ayan, It is really hard to copy paste your code to our visual studio. It would be great if you create [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: @PrasadTelkikar If you see my code, it is just a small function. Are you talking about the json structure by any chance ? That is just for your reference.

Comment: Did you try to debug your code? e.g: Does `title` actually match `"NUnitTestDemo"` in the first iteration? What does `childArray` look like? Is `childArray.Count` actually equal to `1`?

Comment: @Rafalon Yes, it matches the title. The problem is, I am not able to stop the recursion. So, even after the value is found, the recursion keeps going and it returns null.

Comment: Well, you miss a `return` somewhere around `RetrieveSpecifiedJsonObject(propertyName, childArrElem);` - aaand this is what JimmyN answered below ^^

Answer (score 3, accepted):

it returns null because this block doesn't do any action with the result from RetrieveSpecifiedJsonObject

```
if(arrElemTitle != propertyName)
{
   RetrieveSpecifiedJsonObject(propertyName, childArrElem);
}
```

maybe you should do that:

```
if(arrElemTitle != propertyName)
{
   var result = RetrieveSpecifiedJsonObject(propertyName, childArrElem);
   if (result != null)
       return result;
}
```

Comment: Works fine ! Thanks :-)

Answer (score 0):

In addition to what JimmyN wrote in his answer, I'd say that you could simplify your recursive function as such (you already check the `title` property at the top of the function, so you don't need to check it again inside the `for` loop):

```
public JObject RetrieveSpecifiedJsonObject(string propertyName, JObject jsonObject)
{
  //propertyName is the property to be retrieved
  string title = jsonObject.SelectToken("title").ToString();
  if(title != propertyName)
  {            
    JArray childArray = jsonObject.SelectToken("children") as JArray;
    for(int i=0; i<childArray.Count; i++)
    {
      JObject childArrElem = childArray[i] as JObject;
      // the following will already check childArray and all of its children
      JObject result = RetrieveSpecifiedJsonObject(propertyName, childArrElem);
      if(result != null)
        return result;
    }//FOR ENDS
    return null;
  }//IF title != propertyName ENDS
  else
  {
     return jsonObject;
  }
}
```